# What is the equivalent of the "DataProviderTimeout" setting in Sitecore 9

Tags: configuration, settings

I want to temporarily increase the timeout settings in a Sitecore 9 environment while I run the tool for removing broken links (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28725537/how-to-remove-broken-links-in-sitecore).

The answer there mentions the DataProviderTimeout

```
<setting name="DataProviderTimeout" value="00:00:00" />
```

I cannot see this setting in the configs for Sitecore 9. What is the equivalent setting here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's `Sitecore.Configuration.Settings.DefaultSQLTimeout`

```
<!--  DEFAULT SQL TIMEOUT
        The default timeout for all SQL commands issued by the Sitecore APIs, such as
        the SqlServerDataProvider, the OracleDataProvider or the SqlUtil classes.
        Default value: 00:05:00 (5 minutes)
  -->
<setting name="DefaultSQLTimeout" value="00:05:00" />
```

Source:

> [Obsolete("'Sitecore.Configuration.Settings.DataProviderTimeout' is obsolete. Use 'Sitecore.Configuration.Settings.DefaultSQLTimeout' instead.")]

Comment: I had DefaultSQLTimeout already. So I just ignore DataProviderTimeout completely now. Thanks!